# How to get data (2 Lists) back from a class to the StatefulWidget that called it

Tags: flutter

**Problem:** I can't figure out how to get data (2 Lists) back from a class (GraphData) to the Stateful Widget(Price Screen) that called the class(GraphData).

**Background:**
Price Screen (StatefulWidget) makes a call to class GraphData and its getGraphData() function with getData():

price_screen.dart

```
getData() async {
        isWaiting = true;
        try {
          await GraphData().getGraphData(
              selectedCurrency: selectedCurrency,
              selectedGraphType: selectedGraphType);
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
```

GraphData then runs some calculations and creates two Lists: closingTimes and closingPrices.

graph_data.dart

```
class GraphData {
  Future getGraphData(
      {String selectedCurrency,
      String selectedGraphType}) async {
    List<String> closingTimes = [];
    List<double> closingPrices = [];
    .
    . (some calculations here)
    .

        closingTimes.add(formattedClosingTime);
        closingPrices.add(closePrice);

      
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

I need to get these two Lists back to PriceScreen(StatefulWidget) so that I can use them in a later function. How can I do this?

I thought using a callback would work but I couldn't figure out how to set one up in this situation. Note: I cut out as much unnecessary code as I could to simplify my question. I can add more code if need be.

Comment: return is missing

Comment: Yes I know my old code returned something at the end but I am changing my code to return 2 Lists instead. I currently don't know how to do so which is why I left out the return keyword here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either return a `Map<String, List<dynamic>>`:

```
return <String, List<dynamic>>{
  'closingTimes': closingTimes,
  'closingPrices': closingPrices
};
```

---

or you could write a new class:

```
class GraphDataReturnObject {
  final List<String> closingTimes;
  final List<double> closingPrices;

  const GraphDataReturnObject(this.closingTimes, this.closingPrices);
}
```

and

```
return GraphDataReturnObject(closingTimes, closingPrices);
```

and

```
GraphDataReturnObject graphData = await GraphData().getGraphData(...);

// you can access the closing times and closing prices like this:
graphData.closingTimes;
graphData.closingPrices;
```

Comment: Would I create this new GraphDataReturnObject class within my already written GraphData class or in a completely new separate class?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think Dart does not allow to create inner classes.

Comment: Oh I'm not sure since I am still a beginner with Dart. So if I were to create a separate class GraphDataReturnObject, would I reference this class in my GraphData class to pass it the List values closingTimes and closingPrices and then reference it again in my PriceScreen to get the values back?